# Show that $\det(T) = \det(T^*)$

Tags: linear-algebra, dual-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$. Let $T^*$ be the operator on the dual vector space. Show that $\det(T) = \det(T^*)$.

*My attempt* :

We can choose a basis $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ of $V$ such that $T$ is upper triangular. Then $\det(T)$ is the product of the diagonal entries of $T$. I am not sure how to proceed from here. I know that $T^*:V^* \rightarrow V^*$ is such that for $T^*(\phi) = \phi \circ T$ for all $\phi \in V^*$.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Comment: Your notation $V\in\mathbb C$ makes no sense, as that would mean $V$ is a complex number (as opposed to a vector space). What you mean is probably something like "Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb C$".

Comment: Yes, meant $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Do you know that $V^\ast$ has a basis called the *dual basis* to the basis $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ of $V$ ? Do you know that the matrix that represents $T^\ast$ with respect to this dual basis is the transpose of the matrix that represents $T$ with respect to $e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n$ ? (If the answers are "no", you can look up the former and prove the latter.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg Then if $A$ represents the matrix with basis $e_i$ for T, then $A^T$ would be the matrix with the dual basis to $e_i$. Since we picked A to be upper-triangular, $A^T$ is lower-triangular but the determinant is still the product of the diagonal entries. Because the diagonal entries did not change, the product still the same and therefore the determinants are equal. Is my line of reasoning correct?

Comment: Yes, it is, but you can do it without triangularization.

Comment: Yes, however, I am not allowed to use the fact that $det(A^T) = det(A)$ yet.